# trying to bulkify method

Tags: apex

I have the following method that inserts two objects using one insert statement.  The second object has a lookup to the first object and I'm using an external Id to create the relationship.

Method:

```
public static List<InnovationService.Innovation> createInnovations(List<InnovationService.Innovation> innovationsToCreate) {
    List<Idea> ideasToInsert = new List<Idea>();
    List<INN_Innovation__c> innovationsToInsert = new List<INN_Innovation__c>();
    List<InnovationService.Innovation> retval = new List<InnovationService.Innovation>();
    Map<String, Id> ideaMap = new Map<String, Id>();
    if(!innovationsToCreate.isEmpty() && innovationsToCreate.size() > 0) {
        for(InnovationService.Innovation innovation : innovationsToCreate) {
            INN_Innovation__c newInnovation = new INN_Innovation__c();
            newInnovation.Name = innovation.title;
            newInnovation.INN_InnovatorsAwardCategory__c = innovation.awardCategory;
            newInnovation.INN_Experience__c = innovation.experience;
            newInnovation.INN_Resources__c = innovation.resources;
            newInnovation.INN_Measurement__c = innovation.measurement;
            Idea reference = new Idea();
            reference.INN_MasterID__c = innovation.title;
            newInnovation.INN_Idea__r = reference; 
            Idea newIdea = new Idea();
            newIdea.Title = innovation.title;
            newIdea.Body = innovation.description;
            newIdea.INN_MasterID__c = innovation.title;
            newIdea.CommunityId = zoneId;
            ideasToInsert.add(newIdea);
            innovationsToInsert.add(newInnovation);
        }
        Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(new SObject[] { ideasToInsert[0], innovationsToInsert[0] });
        Set<Id> result = new Set<Id>();
        for (Integer i = 0; i < results.size(); i++) {
            if (results[i].isSuccess()) {
                if(String.valueOf(results[i].getId()).substring(0, 3) == 'a07') {
                    result.add(results[i].getId());
                }
            } 
            else {
                System.debug('*************** Error: could not create sobject ' + 'for array element ' + i + '.');
                System.debug('*************** The error reported was: ' + results[i].getErrors()[0].getMessage() + '\n');
            }
        }
        List<INN_Innovation__c> innovationList = [select Id, INN_Idea__c, INN_Idea__r.Title, INN_Idea__r.Body, INN_Idea__r.VoteTotal, INN_InnovatorsAwardCategory__c from INN_Innovation__c where Id in: result];
        InnovationService.Innovation innovation = new InnovationService.Innovation();
        innovation.innovationId = innovationList[0].Id;
        retval.add(innovation);
    }
    return retval;
}
```

The above method is working correctly.  Here is how I would call it:

```
public PageReference save() {
    List<InnovationService.Innovation> innovations = new List<InnovationService.Innovation>();
    InnovationService.Innovation innovation = new InnovationService.Innovation();
    innovation.title = title;
    innovation.description = description;
    innovation.awardCategory = innovationCategory;
    innovation.experience = experience;
    innovation.resources = resources;
    innovation.measurement = measurement;
    innovations.add(innovation);
    List<InnovationService.Innovation> retURL = InnovationService.createInnovations(innovations);
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/apex/InnovationDetail?id=' + retURL[0].innovationId);
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;
}
```

What I'm trying to do now is bulkify the method.  In my database.insert statement I can only pass two single objects. Is there a way to pass two lists of objects and insert both lists in the single insert statement?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of sObjects and add the other lists to it:

```
sObject[] objList = New sObject[]{};
objList.addAll(innovationsToInsert);
objList.addAll(ideasToInsert);
```

then insert the objList.